# Vue 3 template refs dynamic name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-script-setup

I noticed that to make a template ref in Vue 3 composition api `<script setup>`, I should make a variable name with the exact same as the ref value.

For example in [Vue 3 documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs):

```js
<template>
  <div ref="root">This is a root element</div>   <--- notice the ref name "root"
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup() {
      const root = ref(null)   <---- and the variable name should be "root" too

      onMounted(() => {
        console.log(root.value) 
      })

      return {
        root
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I was wondering if I can use the ref the way as Vue 2 do, because I have elements whose ref is random string, and it works on Vue 2 by just passing the name on `$refs` object.

```html
<div ref="myCustomRefName"></div>

<script>
let myRef = this.$refs["myCustomRefName"]
</script>
```

But I can't do that since in Vue3, I should similarize the variable name and the ref prop value. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain your case? You can compose ref objects into a single one that is similar to `refs` and access it by key. Refs can be assigned with ref functions to whatever object you need. They are also accessible on getCurrentInstance() but this shouldn't the first choice.

Comment: @EstusFlask I want to make component library like this `<Modal ref="something"/>` and I want to get the modal component dynamically by the ref. It should be like this `$modal.open('something')`. For that case, I think I need to get the refs object like Vue 2 did

Comment: Check ref function then.

Comment: @AhmadSaugi any solution for this? I want to build an error component which I want to give a unique name so i can call that special ref from a composable.

Answer (score 6):

What worked for me was the following

```
<template>
  <div ref="root">This is a root element</div>   <--- notice the ref name "root"
  <div ref="foo">this is foo element</div>
  <div ref="bar">this is bar element</div>
</template>

<script>
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue'

  export default {
    setup() {
      const refs = {
         root = ref(null), //<---- and the variable name should be "root" too
         foo = ref(null),
         bar = ref(null)
      }
      onMounted(() => {
        console.log(root.value)
        console.log(refs["root"])
      })

      return {
        ...refs
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Just create an object refs (i called it refs just due nostalgia) and call with any dynamic name you have.

Answer (score 4):

Quote from the [`ref` documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/special-attributes.html#ref):

```html
<template>
  <!-- When bound dynamically, we can define ref as a callback function, passing the element or component instance explicitly -->
  <child-component :ref="el => (child = el)"></child-component>
</template>
```

`child` in the above code is a variable, you can name whatever you like ;).